# С чего возникает ошибка net::ERR_ABORTED 404 и как с этим бороться?

Tags: google-chrome, get, сессия

Всех приветствую!
Недавно стал замечать ( в консоли страницы ) странную ошибку
net::ERR_ABORTED 404
Вот как она выглядит:

[image: net::ERR_ABORTED 404]

Самое забавное, что ошибка возникает не всегда, но как решить эту проблему ( на время я знаю ) просто сменить пользователя хром. Но со временем она появляется снова. Объясните пожалуйста, что вообще означает данная ошибка? Из-за чего она появляется и как с этим бороться?
Заранее всем спасибо!

Comment: Собсна 404 говорит сама за себя. Что-то там не найдено

Comment: В том-то и проблема. По сути, я авторизуюсь на 10 разных аккаунтах, соответственно 10 разных пользователей хром. И на 3 это есть в консоли, а на 7 нет. Хотя настройки одни и те же